# Laravel 5.3 : POST request using Ajax always returning Error 404 in console by jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post, laravel-5.3

I'm using `Laravel 5.3` and trying to make a `POST` request using `Ajax - Jquery`. 
For the life of me, I am not able to find what is the mistake I have in my code.

If it helps, I am trying to add a new college details into my table using ajax from admin panel. I have made sure I am making `POST` request and my  `routes/web.php` has a route method with `POST` to receive the request.

My `master.blade.php` has the following line :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content=" {{ csrf_token() }} ">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script> //jQuery v2.1.4
```

In my `view`, I have the following *internal* javascript scripting. I have used `@section` and `@yield` concept to render it as one.

My `settings/home.blade.php` looks like this:

```
@section('scripts')
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function addCollSubmit()
 {

   $.ajaxSetup({

    headers:{
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }

    });


    var formData = new Array();
    for(var i=0 ; i< coll_no; i++)
    {
       var id = "input[name=coll_name_"+i+"]";
       var temp = $(id).val();
       formData.push(temp);
    }

     $.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST',
        headers : { 
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         },
        url:'/admin/settings/addcollege',
        data:formData,
        success:function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $("#reveal-content").html(data);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

   }
  </script>
 @endsection
```

The `form` section in my `settings/home.blade.php` looks like:

```
<form method="POST" name="addCollegeForm" action="">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <table id="addCollTable">
     <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="coll_name_0" placeholder="Enter College Name" /></td>
        <td><a class="button primary" onclick="oneMoreColl()" href="#"><i class="fi-plus"></i></a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">                         
        <a href="#addCollSubmit" onclick="addCollSubmit()" class="button success" >Submit</button></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My `routes/web.php` has the following line to receive the `POST` request :

```
Route::post('admin/settings/addcollege','SettingsController@postIndex');
```

`postIndex()` does have a function definition to store the college details in the table.

Every time I make a request, it generates the following in my developer tools - console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/admin/settings/addcollege
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following url

```
 url:"{{url('/admin/settings/addcollege')}}",
```

Comment: `Error 404` disappeared and `Error 500` appears, although I have set and included the `csrf-field` throughout my requesting process.

Comment: then that means you have a php error in your controller function

Comment: Thanks for the insight. :)

Comment: What should be the appropriate change if I want to move the jQuery code to an external file? Right now it's internal and your solution works.

Comment: you move the ajax to the external file , you place the url in a variable before the reference of the external js file so the ajax has acces to that variable with the url